# Undefined index when accessing multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am having a multi-dimensional array. When I access it I get undefined index but I just can't see what I am doing wrong. I very much appreciate if someone has a glue as I am devastating for quite some while now. Thanks!

Dump:

```
Array
(
[922] => Array
    (
        [products] => Array
            (
                [169] => http://www.golf-safari.com/golf_regions/cape_town.asp
            )

        [company] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 922
                [category_id] => 42
                [language_id] => 1
                [shipping_from_id] => 0
                [name] => Golf-Safari.com
                [logo] => 
                [company_id] => 922
                [area_id] => 414
                [country_id] => 
                [city_id] => 260
                [product_id] => 169
                [url] => http://www.golf-safari.com/golf_regions/cape_town.asp
                [likes] => 0
                [dislikes] => 0
                [views] => 0
            )

    )
)
```

My access code:

```
<?php foreach($items as $cmp_id => $company):
      $item = $company['company']; // throws undefined index company
      $item = $company['products']; // throws undefined index product
?>
<div class="title" title="<?= $item->company ?>">
```

I am not even getting to the div as error is thrown already on $company['company']

Thanks for all the answers! I don't really know whats wrong. Up to now I always assumed that when there is a dump produced then this dump can be accessed, apparently not. I added my preparation code below.

My preparation code:

```
foreach($rows as $row)
    {                   
        if($row->product_id && !in_array($row->product_id, $products)){
            array_push($products, $row->product_id);                
        }           
        $products_count[$row->product_id][] = '1';      

        $ids[$row->id] = $row->id; //store every company id, in order to avoid repetitions count variables  

        $items[$row->id]['products'][$row->product_id] = $row->url; //cities products               
        $items[$row->id]['company'] = $row; 
    }
            if($products && is_array($products)){
                $query = DB::table('products');
                $query->select('id', "name_$this->language AS product");
                $query->whereIn('id', $products);
                $product_names = $query->get();
    }


            $sub['items'] = array(
                'items' => $items,
                'product_names'=> $product_names
            );
```

Comment: What parts of the array are you trying to access?

Comment: please put more code, with the given information, the problem should not occur

Comment: Well, `product` is not part of the array, `products` is.

Comment: *Assuming* that `$items` contains the array you dumped, this *should* work. Produce a complete example we can run ourselves, otherwise we can't really help much.

Comment: sorry for that, I added more code. But I am not getting to the div, the error is thrown on $company['company']. product(s) was a typo

Comment: Do some basic debugging.  If the key you're looking for isn't set, then dump the value and see what's going on.  if ( !isset($company['company']) ) { var_dump($company) }.

Comment: check my comment below, see if it is what you are looking for

Comment: I have my mistake, I created the dump before placing the data into another array so it is nested in another layer. oh boy. Sorry and thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $item = $company['product']; // throws undefined index product

In here you are passing the wrong key use $item = $company['products'];

print_r($company['products']);

2. In $company['company'] its an object so you can access the values by the following way 
   echo $company['company']->name;

Answer (score 1):

the array has about 3 layers. i'll go ahead and assume that the $items is the outtermost layer. according to your structure, your code should look like this:

```
foreach($item[922] as $cmp_id => $company){
       $$cmp_id = $company    //converts the index of the item[922] into a variable and assign them the values
      $item = $$cmp_id['company']; 
      $item = $$cmp_id['product']; 
    }
```

the first $item will hold this value

```
 [company] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 922
            [category_id] => 42
            [language_id] => 1
            [shipping_from_id] => 0
            [name] => Golf-Safari.com
            [logo] => 
            [company_id] => 922
            [area_id] => 414
            [country_id] => 
            [city_id] => 260
            [product_id] => 169
            [url] => http://www.golf-safari.com/golf_regions/cape_town.asp
            [likes] => 0
            [dislikes] => 0
            [views] => 0
        )
```

the second one will hold

```
(
    [169] => http://www.golf-safari.com/golf_regions/cape_town.asp
 )
```

they both contain arrays, i don't think you can use them in the div because none of the new $item arrays has an index [company]. to get the innermost arrays,  change the codes to

```
foreach($items[922][company] as $key => $value){   //or $items[922][products]
  $$key = $value;
}
```

you'll get all the values with their indices as the variable name eg

```
$category_id =42;
```

Comment: i think this is what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

In your example you're overwriting $item each time you declare it. Here is a sample of how to loop through the array - http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/tr0c-u9vh

```
foreach($items as $comp_id => $company){
    $item = $company['products'];
    $company_name = $company['company']['name'];
    print_r($item); // because this is still an array
    echo $company_name; // this is a specific item
}
```

You could also use PHP's recursive iterator class - http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($items)); 
foreach($iterator as $key=>$value){
    echo $key. "\t" . $value . "\n";
}
```

In essence by calling it like this you can flatten the array. http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/5p3h-fb21

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(['variable_by_which_get_dump']['922'] as $values)

{
    foreach($values as $get_subvalue)
    {
        foreach($get_subvalue as $get_final_subvalue)
        {
            echo $get_final_subvalue;
            echo '<br>';        
        }
    }
}
```